# Getting error when converting String to Int in C#

Tags: c#, sitecore

First off I am fairly new to C# but I am trying to convert a string to an Int. I get no errors in Visual Studio but when I actually try to preview my page in Sitecore I get an Error. The error is System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

This is my code:

```
public string numColumnStr = "";
        numColumnStr = parameters.columns;
        int numColumns = 2;
        if (numColumns != null)
            numColumns = Convert.ToInt32(numColumnStr);
```

I want the default value of the columns to be 2. and i have

Comment: What is `parameters.columns`?  I also don't get why you're doing `if (numColumns != null)` when you're directly setting `numColumns` the line before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes, first I used tryparse instead of convert.

Second, I made the judgement call that you meant to compare the string to null, not the integer.  So I updated that line to check if the string is null or empty.

```
public string numColumnStr = "";
        numColumnStr = parameters.columns;
        int numColumns = 2;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(numColumnStr))
            int.TryParse(numColumnStr, out numColumns);
```

Comment: @user3416165, glad I could help. If this solved your issue, please make sure to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are checking the wrong variable. Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
public string numColumnStr = "";
    numColumnStr = parameters.columns;
    int numColumns = 2;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(numColumnStr))
        numColumns = Convert.ToInt32(numColumnStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Johan Hjalmarsson

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that coming string is not a valid integer.

Use `tryParse()`, if it is parsed successfully or it is a valid integer it will return a flag `true`:

```
bool parsed = int.TryParse(numColumnStr,out numColumns);

if(parsed)
    // do something with numColumns here
```

See [**Details  on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the link, this was helpful for me to understand the concept better.

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is quite awkward, it will work with a minor change:

change:

```
if (numColumns != null)
```

to:

```
if (numColumnStr != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the c# code you need:

```
int numColumns = 2; // default value
int.TryParse(parameters.columns, out numColumns);
```

Now I suspect that parameters.columns does not actually point to what you expect. The error you are getting is what would be thrown, if the value was null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Sitecore, you can also make use of the utility functions in Sitecore.Kernel.dll:

```
int numColumns = Sitecore.MainUtil.GetInt(parameters.columns, 2)
```

And FYI, internally the function does the following:

```
public static int GetInt(string value, int defaultValue)
{
  int result;
  if (value == null || value.Length == 0 || !int.TryParse(value, out result))
    return defaultValue;
  else
    return result;
}
```